# mysql left join with two table

Tags: php, mysql

Assuming I have 2 tables:

**leave_type**

```
id       name
1        maternity leave
2        Medical leave
3        Casual Leave
4        Sick Leave
5        honeymoon Leave
```

**employee_leave_blance**

```
id      employee_id      year     leave_type_id     val
1       4                2015      1                9
2       4                2015      2                5
3       8                2015      1                10
4       4                2015      3                4
```

Here `employee_leave_blance.leave_type_id = leave_type.id`

Now I want to get all Leave Type values for `employee_id=4`

In `employee_leave_blance` table for `employee_id=4` there are only 3 leave_type entries but in `leave_type` table there are 5 of them.
I want to get 5 entries for a employee. If no entry is found in `employee_leave_blance` it should return 0.

Let me give an example: I want to get output for `employee_id = 4`

```
employee_id      name                val
4                maternity leave     9
4                Medical leave       5
4                Casual Leave        4
4                Sick Leave          0
4                honeymoon Leave     0
```

For this I've tried following query:

```
select
    el.employee_id, lt.name, el.val  from leave_type as lt
    left join employee_leave_blance as el on el.leave_type_id = lt.id
where
    el.year = YEAR(CURDATE()) and el.employee_id = 4
```

It however returns following results:

```
employee_id      name                val
4                maternity leave     9
4                Medical leave       5
4                Casual Leave        4
```

Now how can I get values for all leave_type for an employee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need, please try :

```
select ifnull(el.employee_id,4) as employee_id,
lt.name,ifnull(el.val,0) as val
from leave_type as lt
left join (select year,employee_id,val,leave_type_id 
                    from employee_leave_balance) as el 
                    on el.leave_type_id = lt.id 
                    and el.year = year(curdate()) 
                    and el.employee_id = 4
```

Actually, your query would works with some modification. just remove `where` clause to `and` because you already joined tables and use `ifnull` function to return 0 for null values. This is your query with some improvement :

```
select
    ifnull(el.employee_id,4) as employee_id, lt.name, ifnull(el.val,0) as val  
from leave_type as lt
    left join employee_leave_balance as el on el.leave_type_id = lt.id
and
    el.year = YEAR(CURDATE()) and el.employee_id = 4
```